# GROUP_CONCAT is an analytic function and must be accompanied by an OVER clause

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying a query using bigquery legacy sql as following:

Data in the table is appended when it gets updated, so first I need to do a subselect of latest updated information (using MAX(updatedOn)), inside I query after.
Tags is a repeated field, with string values.

```
 SELECT
    all._id AS _id
  FROM
    [mytable] AS all
  JOIN EACH (
    SELECT
      _id,
      MAX(updatedOn) AS updatedOn
    FROM
      [mytable]
    GROUP EACH BY
      _id) AS latest
  ON
    all._id = latest._id
    AND all.updatedOn = latest.updatedOn
  WHERE
      AND(NOT  REGEXP_MATCH (GROUP_CONCAT(all.tags), '(query)'))
```

TAGS is a repeated field and I'm trying to select users who don't have the tag **query**.

If I'm not using **group_concat** it will also retrieve users with query tag if they have at least one other tag (because bigquery return multiple rows when you have repeated fields)

So if a user has "x" and "query" tags this query will return it (and I don't want to).
But if the user only has "query" tag if won't be returned.

Hopefully I was clear enough.
I've tried with flatten (mytable, tags) and same result.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of MAX you can use different method to grab the latest row. We have this setup as a view. Adjust as you wish.

```
#legacySQL
SELECT * from (
select rank() over (partition by id order by bq.created DESC, bq.insert_id  desc) as _rank,
*
FROM [dataset:table]
) where _rank=1
```

To obtain in legacy SQL rows that do not contain something is simple as:

```
where NOT services contains 'Google'
```

where `services` in my example is a repeated field

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to express this using `ARRAY_AGG` with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/). Using this pattern, you can select the row associated with the most recent `updatedOn`. For example,

```
#standardSQL
SELECT s.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY updatedOn DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS s
  FROM YourTable AS t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(tags) AS tag WHERE tag LIKE '%query%'
  )
  GROUP BY _id
);
```

Here is a standalone example that you can try:

```
#standardSQL
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS _id, DATE '2017-02-28' AS updatedOn, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] AS tags UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-02-01', ['query01', 'foo'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-03-01', ['bar', '10 query'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-03-03', ['baz'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-03-05', ['query']
)
SELECT s.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY updatedOn DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS s
  FROM YourTable AS t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(tags) AS tag WHERE tag LIKE '%query%'
  )
  GROUP BY _id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood your question is - take most recent entries for each _id and output only those who don't have the tag "query"

Below are versions for BigQuery's both Legacy SQL and Standard SQL

Legacy SQL:

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT _id 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    _id, 
    matches, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY _id ORDER BY updatedOn DESC)  AS latest 
  FROM (
    SELECT _id, updatedOn, SUM(tags LIKE '%query%' ) WITHIN RECORD AS matches
    FROM [mytable]
  )
)
WHERE matches = 0
AND latest = 1
```

Standard SQL:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT s._id
FROM (
  SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY updatedOn DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS s
  FROM `mytable` AS t
  GROUP BY _id
)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(s.tags) AS tag WHERE tag LIKE '%query%'
)
```